# Do we need to delete the collection named system.indexes to make new indexes apply on the collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a question about indexes in MongoDB.

I am using MongoDB version 1.6.5. I am modifying all my collection indexes.

When I used the `show collections` command in my MongoDB shell, it showed one of my collections as

```
system.indexes
stocks
options
```

Do I need to drop the collection `system.indexes` to make the new indexes on the collections apply?

Comment: Also consider updating to a new version of MongoDb. The version you're using is almost 3 years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thew `system.profile` collection is not there however, no you do not. The `profile` collection is the output of the profiler, nothing more. Indexes will still apply.

#### Edit

Since your question says two things, no you do not need to drop `system.indexes` either, MongoDB will handle updating the records in there for you. Dropping it might actually damage your database.

Comment: sorry for the confusion i mean the collection system.indexes . i have edited my question (but i guess i was late )

Comment: Ok Thanks for the clarification , i was about to delete the collection system.indexes , but from your answer i understood that the mongodb internal framework will handle this .